# Chain When Clause's using SqlKata

Tags: c#, sql, sqlkata

Using the SqlKata query builder, I'd like to build up an update query based on values I have.
Given this code:

```
   var query = new Query("Users");

   var user = new User{Age = 28, Name = "John"};


   query.When(user.Age != null, q => q.AsUpdate(new {Age = user.Age}))
       .When(user.Name != null, q => q.AsUpdate(new {Name = user.Name}));
```

the generated sql only has the last truthy clause.

Comment: What would you expect the SQL query to look like? It looks to me like you're building several update queries with different conditions for different column updates. (If this is the case, you have to create a new query for each).

Comment: UPDATE Users SET Age = 28 , Name = "John" WHERE.... I didn't add the Where clause to the question...

Comment: So you want to update multiple columns for each record that match several conditions? Then you just need to use one `.When()`  call with the parameters combined. `.When(user.Age != null && user.Name != null, x => x.AsUpdate(new {Age = 1, Name = "Steve"}));`

Comment: If only one has a value, I want to update that field. If name is null, I still want to update age, and vice versa.

Comment: That should have been specified in your question. To achieve this you want to build the `.AsUpdate()` object as a `ExpandoObject` and then build it up using logic that you define from the data. Once the object is built, you can cast it to a dynamic object and reference it within `.AsUpdate((dyamic)expandoObject)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netcore-3.1 Specifically look at the section header `Enumerating and Deleting Members`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the expected, your code is similar to the following

```
if(age != null)
{
    query.AsUpdate(new {Age = age})   
}

if(name != null)
{
    query.AsUpdate(new {Name = name})   
}
```

in this case, the last truthy statement will always get evaluated.

If you want to use the `.When` methods at least you have to use the 2nd parameter the `WhenNot` to evaluate the `else` part.

```cs
var query = new Query("Users").When(age != null, 
    q => q.AsUpdate(new {Age = age}),
    q => q.When(name != null,  q2 => q2.AsUpdate(new {Name = name}))
);
```

Check this example on the playground here: [WhenNot example](https://sqlkata.com/playground/sqlserver?code=string%20age%20%3D%20null%3B%0Astring%20name%20%3D%20%22ahmad%22%3B%0A%0Avar%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22Users%22)%0A.When(age%20!%3D%20null%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20q%20%3D%3E%20q.AsUpdate(new%20%7BAge%20%3D%20age%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20q%20%3D%3E%20q.When(name%20!%3D%20null%2C%20%20q2%20%3D%3E%20q2.AsUpdate(new%20%7BName%20%3D%20name%7D))%0A)%3B)

But for a more flexible way, I recommend using a dictionary object and filter out the nullable values.

Something similar to ([link](https://sqlkata.com/playground/sqlserver?code=using%20System.Collections.Generic%3B%0Ausing%20System.Linq%3B%0A%0Avar%20values%20%3D%20new%20Dictionary%3Cstring%2C%20object%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22Age%22%2C%20null%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22Name%22%2C%20%22ahmad%22%7D%0A%7D.Where(x%20%3D%3E%20x.Value%20!%3D%20null).ToDictionary(x%20%3D%3E%20x.Key%2C%20x%20%3D%3E%20x.Value)%3B%0A%0Avar%20query%20%3D%20new%20Query(%22Users%22).AsInsert(values)%3B))

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var values = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"Age", null},
    {"Name", "ahmad"}
}.Where(x => x.Value != null).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var query = new Query("Users").AsInsert(values);
```